# How to create a function which accepts variable number of variable arguments?

Tags: delphi

It is possible to create a function which accepts variable number of arguments:

```
function f(const x: array of const): String;
```

and use it this way:

```
f([1,3,4, "hello"]);
```

It is also possible to define an argument as "changeable":

```
function g(var x: Byte): String;

var B: Byte;
g(B);
```

But is it possible to define a function which can take any number of arguments of whatver type and change all of their values?
I know I can do this using pointers but then I don't know the type of the parameter passed so it is quite unsafe to mess with them.

---

I just want to create a function which can return variable number of variables of many different types, not just of 1 type or just 1 variable. And I don't want to write zillions of lines to use the function- it should just be the function itself, no SetLength() before the function call or anything. So here is the best thing I made so far:

```
type TVarArr = Array of Variant;
     PVarArr = ^TVarArr;
Procedure f(a: PVarArr);
var
 i:Integer;
begin
  SetLength(A^, 4);
  a^[0] := 46;
end;

ar: TVarArr;
begin
f(@ar);
caption := IntToStr(ar[0]);
```

Comment: `function f(var x: array of const): String;` as described here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Parameters_(Delphi)#Variant_Open_Array_Parameters

Comment: @DavidHeffernan But I can't invoke it like this: f([a, b, c]) because it gives me an error: "Constant object cannot be passed as var parameter". So how do I call this function?

Comment: OK, I was wrong. You can't do what you want. Sorry

Comment: It's not possible to do this, because the function doesn't receive anything to change. In the case of `f([1, 3, 4, 'hello'])`, what is received is the value 1, 2, 3, and the constant string `hello`. That's why it's called an `array of const` - because it's constant (unchangeable).

Comment: @KenWhite It was not the best example, I think. How about this: f([a, b,c]); These are variables.

Comment: @Tom: As far as the compiler is concerned, they're `const` values, because you're passing them as such. IOW, if `a = 1`, `b = `2`, and `c = 'hello'`, the compiler is passing `[1, 2, 'hello']` - they're treated as `constants` because they're in an `array of const` - that's exactly what the compiler error is telling you with `Constant object cannot be passed as var parameter`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have to use pointers, it can't be `var` because this won't compile: `procedure f2(var a: array of Variant);
begin
  setLength(a, 4); //E2008 Incompatible types
  a[0] := 46;
end;`

Comment: That's an open array. Use a dynamic array: var a: TVarArray. It's clear from your comments that you need to revise your knowledge of open arrays.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks, David. You are the man. And yes- I do need to learn more about open arrays.

Comment: @Tom why don't you try using records? A record can hold any number and type of values and you can pass it as `var` parameter of a function, therefore, any change inside the function will be visible to the caller.

Comment: What version of Delphi are you using?

Comment: @LightBulb I want my function- `f()` to return many values of different types and the types of the values will be defined inside `f()`. I know I can pass record full of variant fields but this is just like a array of variants and I am rather looking for a better solution.

Comment: @MarjanVenema Delphi2005 Pro, Lazarus 1.

Comment: Pity. If you had been on D2010+, you could have put the extended rtti's TValue to good use. A lot faster than Variants....

Comment: @Tom, could you explain the scenario where you'd need to use such a function? If you need such a complex functionality, maybe you're trying to do it the wrong way and there is a much simpler solution to your problem. Please explain (if possible) how and why you want to use this kind of function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tom will not be able to use this answer as his Delphi version isn't high enough, but anybody on D2010 or higher will be able to put the extended rtti's TValue to good use on this type of challenge.

Following is a small console app showing how to:

- create a dynamic array of TValue's from a open array parameter;
- copy a dynamic array of TValue's to a new dynamic array modifying individual values on the way;
- modify the items in a dynamic array of TValues "in place".

Enjoy.

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.Rtti,
  System.SysUtils,
  System.TypInfo;

const
  StringKinds: set of TTypeKind = [tkChar, tkString, tkWChar, tkLString, tkWString, tkUString];

type
  TValueArray = array of TValue;

function ValueArrayFromConstArray(const aSource: array of TValue): TValueArray;
var
  idx: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(aSource));
  for idx := Low(aSource) to High(aSource) do
    Result[idx] := aSource[idx];
end;

function ReturnNewArray(const aSource: TValueArray): TValueArray;
var
  idx: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(aSource));
  for idx := Low(aSource) to High(aSource) do
    if aSource[idx].Kind in StringKinds then
      Result[idx] := 'Dest' + aSource[idx].ToString
    else
      if aSource[idx].Kind in [tkInteger] then
        Result[idx] := 10 + aSource[idx].AsInteger
      else
        Result[idx] := aSource[idx];
end;

procedure ModifyArrayValues(var aArray: TValueArray);
var
  idx: Integer;
begin
  for idx := Low(aArray) to High(aArray) do
    if aArray[idx].Kind in StringKinds then
      aArray[idx] := 'Dest' + aArray[idx].ToString
    else
      if aArray[idx].Kind in [tkInteger] then
        aArray[idx] := 10 + aArray[idx].AsInteger
      else
        ;//aArray[idx] := aArray[idx];
end;

var
  Source: TValueArray;
  Destination: TValueArray;
  Item: TValue;
  idx: Integer;
begin
  Source := ValueArrayFromConstArray(['Some', 42, TObject]);
  Destination := ReturnNewArray(Source);
  idx := 0;
  WriteLn('', #9, 'Old', #9, 'New');
  WriteLn('-', #9, '----', #9, '----');
  for Item in Source do
  begin
    WriteLn(idx, #9, Item.ToString, #9, Destination[idx].ToString);
    Inc(idx);
  end;
  WriteLn;
  WriteLn;
  WriteLn('', #9, 'Modified');
  WriteLn('-', #9, '----');
  Source := ValueArrayFromConstArray(['first', 50, TValue.From<TFloatValue>(fvCurrency)]);
  ModifyArrayValues(Source);
  for Item in Source do
  begin
    WriteLn(idx, #9, Item.ToString);
  end;
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Comment: You're creating a copy of the original array and modifying that copy, not modifying the original array (which is what the question asked), AFAICT. Those appear to be two separate things.

Comment: @KenWhite  In ReturnNewArray I am, in ModifyArrayValues I am not.

Comment: Sure you are. You create the array with `Source := ValueArrayFromConstArray` (which is not the same as passing an `array of const` using `ModifyArrayValues([varA, varB, varC]);` and then pass that **copy** (`Source`) to `ModifyArrayValues`; that's not the same as modifying the original array.

Comment: @KenWhite: Oh, that's the part you are talking about. Yes, there I am creating a new array. It was just a way to get an array with items of various different types easily initialized (ie without having to do SetLength). I am sure that it could be "improved" to do some in place magic as open array's are cast compatible with dynamic ones. But why? I don't read that as a requirement in the question. I read OP somewhat cryptic question and various comments to just wanting to be able to  to return an array with items of different types or modify the items in one when passed into a function.

Comment: You can do that with an `array of Variant`. The question was specifically about changing the values of an array created as `func([a, b, c])` where `a` and `b` are different types than `c` (see the first code snippet in the original question). There's a difference between an `array of Variant` and an `array of const` - which I'm sure you know :-). I don't know if you can see Tom's deleted "answer" (which was an extended comment posted as an answer) or not; I don't remember what rep is required for that off-hand, but it mentions that as well.

Comment: @KenWhite: Yes, that's why I used an array of TValue, not an array of const as the input to the function initializing the array. And the deleted viewing limit is 10k so I can see Tom's deleted answer, which was turned into an edit on his question. He says `I just want to create a function which can return variable number of variables of many different types,` and doesn't have any input parameters on his function, just a pointer to his array... That doesn't ask for modifying a literal open array into a dynamic one. And achieving his goal should be easy, given the various examples in my answer.

Comment: ;-) I guess we have to agree to disagree (and I am NOT downvoting your answer). But the original question asks about declaring a function taking `array of const`, using it like `func([1, 2, 3, 'hello'])` and being able to change the array values inside `func`, and your answer doesn't provide that - it provides a way to use an `array of TValue`, which is **not** the equivalent of `array of const`. (If it was, it would be compatible with all versions of Delphi back to D1, which supports `array of const` declarations and does not require RTTI to use.) (more...)

Comment: (more) Your answer also requires creating the array separately (using `ValueArrayFromConstArray`) and then modifying that second array, which is not the same as the question asked about doing. Your answer would work (sort of) if you could just do `ModifyArray([val1, 'val2', True, 124.35])` and alter the array content. (Which, now that I think about it, makes no sense because you can't access the array after it's been modified anyway; it would be gone after `ModifyArray` returned, and therefore the entire question has no meaning. :-))

Comment: @KenWhite: Answering questions that have no meaning is my favourite waste of time :-)) Oh, wait, no, that no longer applies... second favourite waste of time then.

Answer (score 1):

```
Procedure All(var a:Array of Variant);
var
 i:Integer;
begin
  for I := Low(a) to High(a) do
      begin

        if VarType(a[i])=258  then
          a[i] := a[i] + ' modified';

      end;
end;

Procedure AllConst( a:Array of Variant);
var
 i:Integer;
begin
  for I := Low(a) to High(a) do
      begin
        Showmessage(a[i]);
      end;
end;


procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 a:Array of Variant;
begin
  AllConst([1,2,'Test']);
  SetLength(a,3);
  a[0] := 3.141;
  a[1] := 'Test';
  a[2] := 27;
  all(a);
  Showmessage(a[1]);
end;
```

Comment: The problem with this is AllConst accepts variable number of parameters, but can't change them and All() can change parameters but accepts only 1 of them.

Comment: @David Heffermann, that's right , never had to write my own varianttypes ... http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2010/08/07/a-magical-gathering-part-2/

Comment: How about something like this: Procedure All(out a:Array of Variant); begin
  SetLength(A, 4); //this doesn't compile, but if it did it would be a nice solution
end;

Comment: this will compile ....
type
TVariantArray=Array of Variant;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure All(out a:TVariantArray);
begin
   SetLength(a,10);
   a[1] := 'Test';
end;

procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 a:TVariantArray;
begin
     All(a);
     Showmessage(a[1]);
end;